# VBA Concatenating Strings with Dates

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a sub to save my excel worksheet with a timestamp of when it was saved, I am not VBA experienced at all and the error makes me think I should define the Datetime.now as a variable but even that did not work, if i did it right.

```
Sub SaveToDir()
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("T:\BRojas\test2" & Text(DateTime.Now()) & ".xlsx")

End Sub
```

My error says

```
Compile error: Sub or Function not defined
```

Thanks.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("T:\AWilliams\test2" & CStr(DateTime.Now()) & ".xlsx")  should work

Comment: It doesn't work, just tried it. I got "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' Failed"

Comment: See the answers below as the issue is with the format of the datetime slashes and colons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Text` is an Excel worksheet function.  The equivalent in VBA is `Format`.

So you want to use:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "T:\AWilliams\test2" & Format(DateTime.Now(), "yyyymmdd-hhmmss") & ".xlsx"
```

Use whatever date/time format you prefer instead of the "yyyymmdd-hhmmss" that I used above.  But don't include slashes (`/`) or colons (`:`) because they aren't valid in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

As Sorceri commented, that should work, but you might still have to replace the Colons in the timestamp before it will save.

Try

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("T:\AWilliams\test2" & replace(CStr(DateTime.Now()),":","-") & ".xlsx")
```

Comment: Slashes (`/`) are invalid too.